# Retrieve, manipulate and send back JSON in Ansible

Tags: json, ansible

We have to set and unset a VLAN configuration to a switch. Fortunately, Unify Controller provide an API, which works with Ansible in general.

However, it is not possible with the API to change a single element, Ansible has to get the current configuration, find and change the desired element and send back the configuration. (I pushed the desired config change. This yielded to the situation that the switch had nothing but my config change, I felt like the Facebook guys...)

```
---
- hosts: adm01.local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

  - name: Use vars from Vault
    include_vars: unifi_info.yaml

  - name: Get Cookie from Unifi
    uri:
      url: https://{{ url }}/api/login
      method: POST
      body_format: json
      body: {"username":"{{ username }}","password":"{{ password }}"}
      validate_certs: false
    register: login

  - name: Print returned data to ensure it worked
    debug:
      msg: "{{ login }}"

  - name: Get current config
    uri:
      url: https://{{ url }}/api/s/default/stat/device/
      method: GET
      body_format: json
      headers:
        Cookie: "{{ login.cookies_string }}"
      validate_certs: false
    register: switchConf

  - name: Print SwitchConf
    debug:
      msg: "{{ switchConf }}"

  - name: Set port 2 to CLIENTVLAN
    uri:
      url: https://{{ url }}/api/s/default/rest/device/60acc79964542d80774123b5/
      method: PUT
      body_format: json
      # DISABLE VLAN: "60aca5ee64542d807741239d"
      # CLIENTVLAN: ""60accb9b64542d80774123d1"
      #body: {"port_overrides": [{"port_idx": 2, "portconf_id":"60accb9b64542d80774123d1"}]}
      headers:
        Cookie: "{{ login.cookies_string }}"
      validate_certs: false
    register: portConf

  - name: Print portConf
    debug:
      msg: "{{ portConf }}"
```

SwitchConf prints (the relevant part, only):

```
    "msg": {
        "access_control_allow_credentials": "true",
        "access_control_expose_headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
        "changed": false,
        "connection": "close",
        "content_type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "cookies": {},
        "cookies_string": "",
        "date": "Wed, 20 Oct 2021 18:22:24 GMT",
        "elapsed": 0,
        "failed": false,
        "json": {
            "data": [
                {
                    (...)
                    "port_overrides": [
                        {
                            "port_idx": 1,
                            "portconf_id": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "port_idx": 2,
                            "portconf_id": "B"
                        },
                        {
                            "port_idx": 3,
                            "portconf_id": "B"
                        },
                        {
                            "port_idx": 5,
                            "portconf_id": "B"
                        },
                        {
                            "port_idx": 6,
                            "portconf_id": "B"
                        },
                        {
                            "port_idx": 7,
                            "portconf_id": "B"
                        },
                        (...)
                    ],
                    (...)
                }
            ]
        },
        "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)",
        "redirected": false,
        "status": 200,
        "transfer_encoding": "chunked",
        "url": "https://adm01.local:8443/api/s/default/stat/device/",
        "vary": "accept-encoding,origin,accept-encoding",
        "x_frame_options": "DENY"
    }
}
```

So, the question is: how can Ansible be used to fetch the JSON datagram portConf->data->port_overrides and change the "portconf_id" to "X" with "port_idx"==2, so that post_overrides can be used to POST it back?

Comment: *json.data* is the list of dictionaries. There is only one dictionary in the example, but, because it's a list, there might be more items. How do you know in which item to change *port_overrides*? [edit] the question and make it [mre].

Comment: The other parts of json.data are irrelevant. The values of portconf_id are irrelevant as well. You used in your answer letters, I'll change it to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionaries in YAML are immutable. You have to create a new one to change anything. Given the simplified data

```yaml
    portConf:
      status: 200
      json:
        data:
          - port_overrides:
              - port_idx: 1
                portconf_id: A
              - port_idx: 2
                portconf_id: B
              - port_idx: 3
                portconf_id: C
```

and the required changes

```yaml
    diff:
      port_idx: 2
      portconf_id: X
```

the task below makes the changes in *json.data*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _json: "{{ {'data': [{'port_overrides': _port_change}]} }}"
      vars:
        _port_remove: "{{ portConf.json.data.0.port_overrides|
                          rejectattr('port_idx', 'eq', diff.port_idx)|
                          list }}"
        _port_change: "{{ (_port_remove + [diff])|sort(attribute='port_idx') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _json:
    data:
    - port_overrides:
      - port_idx: 1
        portconf_id: A
      - port_idx: 2
        portconf_id: X
      - port_idx: 3
        portconf_id: C
```

and the next task combines the changes

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        portConf: "{{ portConf|combine({'json': _json}) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  portConf:
    json:
      data:
      - port_overrides:
        - port_idx: 1
          portconf_id: A
        - port_idx: 2
          portconf_id: X
        - port_idx: 3
          portconf_id: C
    status: 200
```

Comment: Thx @vladimir-botka . I changed the line to _json: "{{ {'port_overrides': _port_change} }}" to skip unneeded structures and added _diff: "{{ {'port_idx': 2, 'portconf_id':'60aca5ee64542d807741239d'} }}" to the vars, By doing this I can use _json direct to push it to the controller. Works great.